# python iterating multiple lists in multiple loops

Tags: python, list, loops

I need to iterate through multiple lists, and do some calculations for the matching records:

```
for (a,b,c,d) in list1:
   for (a2,b2,e) in list2:
       if (a==a2) and (b==b2):
           mylist.add(a,b,c,d,e,d*e)
```

Is there an efficient way of doing the above calculation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give us an example of how the lists look?

Comment: For a start, in the outer loop ` If a != b: continue`

Comment: @ColBeseder: I'm guessing that the intent was `if (a==a2) and (b==b2)`, but I agree that OP should clarify.

Comment: List may look like
list1 = (name, last_name, gender, job_class, salary)
list2 = (name, last_name, increase)

and assume one more list, 

list3 = (job_class, bonus)

so need to find all matching records, so that

Comment: List may look like
list1 = (name, last_name, gender, job_class, salary)
list2 = (name, last_name, increase)

and assume one more list, 

list3 = (job_class, bonus)

so need to find all matching records, so that

for (name, last_name, gender, job_class1, salary) in list1:
    for (name2, last_name2, increase) in list 2:
        if (name==name2) and (last_name==last_name2):
            for (job_class2, bonus) in list3:
                if(job_class==job_class2):
                    final_list.add(name, last_name, salary*increase + bonus)

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong data structures for the job. Please show some actual code and some actual data to work with.

Answer (score 5):

Build some dictionaries for fast lookup:

```
data1 = {(a, b): (c, d) for a, b, c, d in list1}
data2 = {(a, b): e for a, b, e in list2}

result = []
for a, b in set(data1) & set(data2):
    c, d = data1[a, b]
    e = data2[a, b]
    result.append((a, b, c, d, e, e*d))
```

Comment: Worth pointing out, this is slower than the implementation in the question for datasets in the thousands.

Comment: @adsmith: Really? Shouldn't this be O(N) vs O(N^2)?

Comment: @adsmith: I find that very hard to believe.  I could believe it was slower for lists of very small size, but for even moderate size I think the algorithmic complexity here has to win.  @Eric: Note that this assumes that everything is unique in `(a,b)`; not unreasonable, but not clear to me from the question.  (Not sure how the OP is handling two people with the same name, e.g.)

Comment: I generated dummy lists of 2,000 entries for `list1` and 1,000 entries for `list2`. There WERE many duplicate entries, so it's possible that's caused the flip in efficiency. With actual data, a dictionary may provide faster lookup, but it's harder to test without some real data and I'm not about to generate dummy data 2,000 items large to run `timeit` on!

Answer (score 2):

With the new information in mind, that:

1. `list1`'s elements are of the form `(name, last_name, gender, job_class, salary)`,
2. `list2` is contains elements of the form `(name, last_name, increase)` (presumably a raise for a person),
3. `list3` is has elements like `(job_class, bonus)`,

... you may benefit in both performance and code clarity using a `dict`.

Using a tuple of the form `(first,last)` to reference each person in your program, you can do something like this (in a basic example with `input` to get information):

```
people = dict()
for i in range(num_ppl):
    name = tuple(input().split()) # input is something like "Bob Smith"
    people[name] = getPeopleInfo() # read gender, job_class, salary, etc. and make a list
for i in range(num_raises):
    first, last, increase = input().split()
    people[(first,last)][-1] *= float(increase)
for i in range(num_bonuses):
    job_class, bonus = input().split()
    for name in people: # iterating through a dict gives the keys (similar to indices of a list, but can be immutable types such as tuples)
        if people[name][2] == job_class:
            people[name][-1] += bonus
```

Any immutable type such as `str`, `int` and `tuple` can be used as a key in a `dict`, similar to the 0-based integers used for a `list`.  Note that a `list` can change (e.g. using `list.append`) and is "mutable"; therefore a `list` cannot be a key.  For more information about `dict` you can read up on the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of time and memory efficiency, the current code seems mostly optimal.  You have to check all of the elements of `list1` and `list2` against each other for your comparisons.
One addition to eliminate some repeated "wrong" cases is to add between the two `for` loop lines:

```
if a != b: # none of the items in list2 will satisfy a==b2 and b==b2
    continue
```

You can also use `if a == b == b2` in Python instead of having to tie the statements together with `and`.

Depending on how your records are stored and accessed, you may benefit from using `dict`s over `list`s.  A `dict` can tell if some An example of its implementation might be:

```
lookup = dict()

# when adding an item to what would be list2
if b2 in not in lookup:
    lookup[b2] = []
lookup[b2].append((a2,e))
# ...

for (a,b,c,d) in list1:
    if a == b and a in lookup:
        for (a2,e) in lookup[a]:
            mylist.add(a,b,c,d,e,d*e)
```

Comment: Careful, it should have been `if a==a2 and b==b2:`- there is a typo in the question, but the comments make it clear.

Comment: List may look like list1 = (name, last_name, gender, job_class, salary) list2 = (name, last_name, increase) and assume one more list, list3 = (job_class, bonus) so need to find all matching records, so that for (name, last_name, gender, job_class1, salary) in list1: for (name2, last_name2, increase) in list 2: if (name==name2) and (last_name==last_name2): for (job_class2, bonus) in list3: if(job_class==job_class2): final_list.add(name, last_name, salary*increase + bonus)